# Pandas: merge two time series and get the mean values during the period when these two have overlapped time period

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, time, merge

I got two pandas dataframes as following:

```
ts1
Out[50]: 
                     soil_moisture_ids41  
date_time                                 
2007-01-07 05:00:00               0.1830  
2007-01-07 06:00:00               0.1825  
2007-01-07 07:00:00               0.1825  
2007-01-07 08:00:00               0.1825  
2007-01-07 09:00:00               0.1825  
...                                 ...  
2017-10-10 20:00:00               0.0650  
2017-10-10 21:00:00               0.0650  
2017-10-10 22:00:00               0.0650  
2017-10-10 23:00:00               0.0650  
2017-10-11 00:00:00               0.0650  

[94316 rows x 3 columns]
```

and the other one is

```
ts2
Out[51]: 
                     soil_moisture_ids42  
date_time                                                        
2016-07-20 00:00:00                0.147  
2016-07-20 01:00:00                0.148  
2016-07-20 02:00:00                0.149  
2016-07-20 03:00:00                0.150  
2016-07-20 04:00:00                0.152  
...                                 ...  
2019-12-31 19:00:00                0.216 
2019-12-31 20:00:00                0.216 
2019-12-31 21:00:00                0.215 
2019-12-31 22:00:00                0.215 
2019-12-31 23:00:00                0.215 

[30240 rows x 3 columns]
```

You could see that, from `2007-01-07` to `2016-07-19`, only `ts1` has the data points. And from `2016-07-20` to `2017-10-1`1 there are some overlapped time series. Now I want to combine these two data frames. During the overlapped period, I want to get the mean values over `ts1` and `ts2`. During the non-overlapped period, (`2007-01-07` to `2016-07-19` and `2017-10-12` to `2019-12-31`), the values at each time stamp is set as the value from `ts1` or `ts2`. So how can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `mean`, if only one value get same ouput, if multiple get `mean`. Also finally `DatatimeIndex` is sorted:

```
s = pd.concat([ts1, ts2]).groupby(level=0).mean()
```

Comment: Thanks! but what does it mean by ".groupby(level=0)"? and (in another INDEPEDENT case) I see that if I use ```.mean()```, the multiple data points on one time stamp will disappear. Say, if I got 3 data points on ```2019-12-31``` (just YYYYMMDD, excluding HH, i.e. not ```2019-12-31 20:00:00```), then after using ```.mean()```, the final results only retain one data point which is the mean value of those 3 data points...so what can I do to keep the original 3 data points? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just store the concatenated series first and then apply the mean. i.e. `merged_ts = pd.concat([ts1, ts2])` and then `mean_ts = merged_ts.group_by(level=0).mean()`